# different results for openssl base64 and PHP base64_encode

Tags: php, openssl, base64

I am trying to base64 encode a string in PHP and openssl.

openssl: echo -n "1234567890A" | openssl enc -base64

php:

```
$hash = sha1("1234567890A", true);
var_dump($hash);
echo base64_encode($hash);
```

the results differ:

openssl: MTIzNDU2Nzg5MEE=

PHP:     /Q6nenquhGpX5h2WdiQZQF47Pe8=

I guess this is just a simple setting I can use to adapt result 1 or 2, since PHP produces a string of exact the double size of string 1.

Please help me out.
Many thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why are you taking *SHA1 hash* of it? Just do this:**

```
 echo base64_encode("1234567890A");

 // Output: MTIzNDU2Nzg5MEE=
```

Comment: I'm a bit ashamed of having asked - sorry for bothering and thanks.